# UiPath : Read value as String from EventObjectIDType[]

Tags: arrays, json, object, uipath, workday-api

I'm facing an issue to read a value from uipath workday - launch eib IntegrationEvent Output variable.

See attached image for variable type and the value i want to read is the "a428838...0000"

[image]

Using Log Message, i get this output "UiPath.Workday.Integrations.EventObjectIDType[]"

Unable to cast as string: CType(IntegrationEvent.Background_Process_Instance_Data.Parent_Event_Reference.ID.SyncRoot,String)

Unable to cast as enumerable:
CType(IntegrationEvent.Background_Process_Instance_Data.Parent_Event_Reference.ID.SyncRoot,IEnumerable)

Unable to deserialize JSON also from the output